# How can i have multiple Navbars in a page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am building a CMS editor and one of the things that can be customized is the text appearing in the Navbar. I am having a problem with showing two Navbars. Most examples i have seen are multiple Navbars one below the other and is not what i need.

I need the first Navbar to be the editor's own Navbar, while the second Navbar is somewhere below the first Navbar but not directly below it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `navbar-fixed-top` from the second nav

html would be like this

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">

   <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>

      <div class="container">

  <h1>Conent</h1>
  <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

   </div> <!-- /container -->
   <div class="navbar ">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">


  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

[in bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DE4rfnBY0a)